# It seems the mode rewrite in .htaccess apache is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, openfire

I am trying to run [iJab](http://code.google.com/p/ijab/) with Openfire server which requires me to redirect the /http-bind request to localhost:7070/http-bind. 
I copied the  iJAb folder into my document root and wrote the following code inside .htaccess file within the directory

```
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +Indexes
    Options +MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule /http-bind/ http://localhost:7070/http-bind/ [P]
```

In httpd.conf , its  AllowOverride all

But when I run it, it gives error .. username or password error but firebug console shows  404 error on the ajax post request to

```
http://localhost/http-bind
```

. So i have a doubt if its being redirected at all. Is there any way to check if htaccess is actually used or not?

Also, I am not using any virtual host, the server name for both apache server and the openfire server is localhost and address is 127.0.0.1. I let that be since the openfire admin works perfectly on 9090 port and the port for http-bind is 7070

Can this be the reason?

Looking for some ideas

Answer (score 1):

In case of .htaccess, you need to remove the local path prefix from your pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^http-bind(/.*)?$ http://localhost:7070/http-bind/ [P]
```

Comment: thanks .. but still no luck. Can you pls explain what you meant by "in case of .htaccess" .. is there any other alternative

Comment: @naiquevin: If you use mod_rewrite in a per-directory file like *.htaccess*, it removes the contextual path prefix before testing the patterns and appends them back after applying a rule (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase). That’s why the leading `/` is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The rule you're using has a slash at the end, but the URL you're using doesn't.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake . the request also has the trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

The link for the http bind should be put in the index file of the example folder and not in the htaccess file as shown in the snipet below.the htaccess file is not really being accessed.hope this helps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Candy.init('http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind/', {
    core: {
        // only set this to true if developing / debugging errors
        debug: true,
        // autojoin is a *required* parameter if you don't have a plugin (e.g. roomPanel) for it
        //   true
        //     -> fetch info from server (NOTE: does only work with openfire server)
        //   ['test@conference.example.com']
        //     -> array of rooms to join after connecting
        //autojoin: true
    },
    view: { assets: '../res/' }
});
```